# the menu does not show in the click

Tags: android

I am trying to create a menu in my application but when I run my application there is an error that appears and the error goes off when I click on the menu I understand dou comes this error and how I can correct it help me please...here is the error that appears
the menu code

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item
       android:id="@+id/meu_showmsg"
       android:icon="@drawable/menuh"
       android:state_pressed="true"
       android:title="@string/se_connecter"
       app:showAsAction="always" />

      </menu>
```

code Activity

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.meu_showmsg:
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title("Se connecter").show();
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bein_markt_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: zied.aloui.beinmarkt, PID: 3780
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060063
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
                  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:125)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:210)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:187)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:196)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:476)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1164)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:291)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1051)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1078)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1419)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1657)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:134)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: How are you implementing your code?

Comment: Add the code that you have written.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060063
```

and this:  
`at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)`  
indicate that probably one of the icons you use for the menu does not exist, maybe you misspelled it.